# images not loading in websockets

Tags: websocket

I have a problem loading images

```
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    alert('it loaded');
bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";
```

the alert does not appear when the websocket server is running.
The alert will appear if I remove the socket code and turn the server off.
I have already placed alerts throughout the code to see how far it will run without breaking.
Nothing seems to be breaking except the image does not seem to want to load.
any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing files from a different port so thats why they were not loading